# Carrierwave: pseudo version for dynamic resizing

Tags: ruby, carrierwave

In order to be able to have dynamic image sizes ( yeah. i know ) i came up with the following `version` which just creates a temporary file on each request ( jap, stupid i know -- [ store file in cache based on args ?  ])

```
version :resized do 
  def url(*args) 
    width,height,gravity,region = args[0],args[1],args[2],args[3]
    manipulate! do |img|
      cols, rows = img[:dimensions]
      img.combine_options do |cmd|
        if width != cols || height != rows
          scale = [width/cols.to_f, height/rows.to_f].max
          cols = (scale * (cols + 0.5)).round
          rows = (scale * (rows + 0.5)).round
          cmd.resize "#{cols}x#{rows}"
        end
        cmd.gravity gravity
        cmd.extent "#{width}x#{height}#{region}" if cols != width || rows != height
      end
      img = yield(img) if block_given?
      img
    end 
    convert "jpg"
    super() 
  end 
end
```

The problem i am having is that since i don't `process` this version it quasi duplicates the original and uses it for the 'on-request' manipulation. If that original file was a 100MB tiff this gets messy !
So now i am looking for a way to keep that version from actually creating a file and to use a different version's file for that 'on-request' manipulation.
Any ideas ?